# No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=arm6 arm7, VALID_ARCHS=armv7)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am constantly getting below error while building app:

```
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=arm6 arm7, VALID_ARCHS=armv7).
```

I tried adding `arm6 arm7` to architecture but didn't work. I also tried just `arm6` and `arm7`, but still not.

Also, I'm setting deployment target to `4.3 iPhone`.
I have Xcode version `4.3.1`.

Please help!

Comment: At the end of all warnings I am getting all apps should include an armv7 architecture (current ARCHS = "")

Comment: Set "Build Active Architecture Only" to "NO" for all your dependent libraries and framework, and your target.

Comment: What does build active architecture only mean?

Comment: Hey @iOSDev! Could you accept the answer that helped you, there are no accepted answers to this question at the moment...

Answer (score 26):

You must take two steps:

- Go to `Project Target > Build Settings > Architectures`
  Delete whatever you see there, and then add these rows one by one:

  armv6
  armv7

There are no 'save' buttons there, so what I do, is adding another blank row, pressing enter, removing it, and then clicking out somewhere else, so that I make sure I have both of them added:

[image]

- Now go to the AppName-Info.plist file, and look for the key "Require device capabilities" and delete it all.

Now it's done.

Answer (score 18):

set "Build Active Architecture Only" = NO
this worked for me after upgrading an old project to xcode5

Comment: But if we open project in Xcode 4.x then the error pops-up.

Answer (score 14):

That works fine for me:

Set **architectures** to "**Standard (armv7,armv7s)**" and after set manually **Valid architectures** to **armv7 armv7s**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not arm6 and arm7, try by adding armv6 and armv7 as architectures.

Comment: No, I am not adding "and" in between.

Comment: It's not the AND that's important, it's the V - arm*v*6

Answer (score 0):

Add architectures only armv7. Remove armv6 then try it.

Comment: I also tried Not working for me with xcode 4.5 and iostarget 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the latest Xcode and iPhone5. I had it set to armv7s and armv7.  It took care of my issue which was the `No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7)` error
.

Answer (score 0):

To include 64 bit:
Set architectures to `"$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT)"` and after set manually Valid architectures to `armv7 arm64`. My Xcode version was 5.1. Base SDK was iOS 7.1
Deployment target was 6.0.

In another setting configuration:
Set architectures to `"$(ARCHS_STANDARD)"` and after set manually valid architectures to `armv7 arm64`. My Xcode version was 6.2. Base SDK was iOS 8.2
Deployment target was 6.0.