# iPhone 5S Specific Error: No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=arm64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, compilation

My app uses a few libraries that are iPhone hardware specific and do not run on the simulator. My app complies and runs fine on an iPhone 5 with iOS 7.1, iPod Touch 5G with iOS 7.0 and iPhone 4 with iOS 6.

However, when I try to compile it to a specific iPhone 5S with iOS 7.1, I get the following error, which doesn't make much sense to me:

```
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=arm64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s).
```

As a note, this works on other iPhone 5S's - it's just this specific.

Comment: Try to validate your projects settings in xcode (i.e. select it from the right side bar then editor->validate settings)

Comment: unfortunately, the settings are valid and I still get the error

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005896/no-architectures-to-compile-for-archs-arm6-arm7-valid-archs-armv7?rq=1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you tried looking at your project settings and making sure that under Architectures, `Valid Architectures` includes `arm64`? It looks like it's only including `armv7` and `armv7s`. Make sure the architectures are included as such:

[image]

You may also decide to set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `No` so it can build regardless of what architecture you're connected to.

Comment: thanks - arm64 was on the valid architectures line, but some of the other settings were slightly different. Setting build active architecture to No seemed to fix it.