# Updating Xcode from 5.0.2 to 5.1

Tags: xcode

I've updated Xcode 5.0.2 to 5.1. but it gives me an error I don't know how it will be fixed.

[image]

Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: There are plenty of answers for your problem on the net and on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549478/iphone-compiler-fails-no-architectures-to-compile-for, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005896/no-architectures-to-compile-for-archs-arm6-arm7-valid-archs-armv7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889065/no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x86-64-valid.

Answer (score 0):

Heyy try below. May it will help

> goto Project-> Build Setting-> search ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH ->set Debug YES to NO